# how to disabled accordion tab?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want disabled shipping tab.when it will open means if i fill all details in billing information tab without an error like email validation, required fields etc..once i filled all correct values then click shipping information tab then only open.otherwise i dont want open shipping tab.it should be disabled.
 see picture:
   [image]

```
<div id="accordion-container accordion-header_Static " class="checkout-accordion">
   <h2 id="h2login" class="accordion-header">Login</h2>
   <h2 id="h2BillingInformatio" class="accordion-header accordion-header_Static">Billing Information</h2>
   <div id="divBillingInformatio" class="accordion-content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" Text=""
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="Bill"
               CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Last Name <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" Text=""
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtLastName" ValidationGroup="Bill"
               CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </div>
      </div>
      <label>Company Name</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
      <label>Address <span>*</span></label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" placeholder="Street Address" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddressLine1" runat="server" Text=""
         SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtAddressLine1" ValidationGroup="Bill"
         CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine2" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Apartment, suite, unit, etc. (if applicable)"></asp:TextBox>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>City <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCity" runat="server" Text="City is required" ControlToValidate="txtCity"
               SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Bill" CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCountry" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <ContentTemplate>
                  <div id="pStateFields" runat="server" visible="true">
                     <label>State<span>*</span></label>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" onchange="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="select" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="StateRowId" ForeColor="#000">
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Text=""
                        SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="ddlState" ValidationGroup="Bill"
                        InitialValue="" CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     <br />
                  </div>
               </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Zip <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" onkeypress="return OnlyNumber(event,this.id);" runat="server" CssClass="inputTxt" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvZip" runat="server" Text="Zip is required" ControlToValidate="txtZip"
               SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Bill" CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Text="ZipCode must be numeric"
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtZip" ValidationGroup="Bill" CssClass="QtyError"
               Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^\d*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <br />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Email <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" CssClass="inputTxt" ClientIDMode="Static" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" Text=""
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="Bill"
               CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" Text="Email is in invalid format"
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="Bill"
               Display="Dynamic" CssClass="QtyError" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Phone <span>*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" onkeyup="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" runat="server" CssClass="inputTxt" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhone" runat="server" Text=""
               SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ValidationGroup="Bill"
               CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <h2 id="h2ShippingInformatio" class="accordion-header accordion-header_Static" onclick="shippingTab();">Shipping Information</h2>
   <div id="divShippingInformatio" class="accordion-content second-row">
      <%--<input id="ShippingCheck" type="checkbox" checked onclick="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" />--%>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="ShippingCheck" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="chkSameAs_OnCheckChanged()" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hfchkShippingCheck" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
      <label>&nbsp;Same as Billing Address</label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <fieldset id="ShippingForm" disabled runat="server" clientidmode="static">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtshipInfoFirstName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtshipInfoFirstName" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <label>Last Name <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtshipInfoLastName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtshipInfoLastName" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
         </div>
         <label>Company Name</label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipInfoCompany" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
         <label>Address <span>*</span></label>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtshipInfoAddressLine1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Street Address"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" Text=""
            SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtshipInfoAddressLine1" ValidationGroup="Ship"
            CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtshipInfoAddressLine2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Apartment, suite, unit, etc. (if applicable)"></asp:TextBox>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <label>City <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtshipInfoCity" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtshipInfoCity" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <label>State<span>*</span></label>
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upShipInfoCountry" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                     <div id="p1" runat="server" visible="true">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShipInfoState" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="select" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="StateRowId" ForeColor="#000">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvddlShipInfoState" runat="server" Text=""
                           SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="ddlShipInfoState" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                           InitialValue="" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <br />
                     </div>
                  </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
               <label>Zip <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipInfoZip" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="StateTaxBind()" onkeypress="return OnlyNumber(event,this.id);"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoZip" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revQuantity" runat="server" Text="ZipCode must be numeric"
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoZip" ValidationGroup="Ship" CssClass="QtyError"
                  Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^\d*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <label>Email <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipInfoEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeyup="errortxtShipInfoEmails()"></asp:TextBox>
               <span id="errortxtShipInfoEmail" class="QtyError" style="display: none"></span>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoEmail" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               <%--asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" Text="Email is in invalid format"
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoEmail" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  Display="Dynamic" CssClass="QtyError" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></%--asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
               <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgvdfd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoEmail" Text="email is in invalid format" CssClass="QtyError" ValidationGroup="Ship" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <label>Phone <span>*</span></label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipInfoPhone" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" Text=""
                  SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtShipInfoPhone" ValidationGroup="Ship"
                  CssClass="QtyError" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        //alert('0');
    }

    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        //alert('1');
    }
});
```